# I can't sync the db using south due to an AttributeError

Tags: python, database, django, ubuntu, django-south

After [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14970936/1505348) an error trying to migrate, now I'm facing another issue with the `south` package.

Running `manage.py syncdb` or `manage.py schemamigration MyApp --initial` I get [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6724962/):

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458553/1505348) mentions that the issue is solved with the new version (`0.8.4`) but not for me 'cause I have the latest one.

I'm running over a virtual enviroment with python3.3 - Any clue?

---

If you didn't see the link or don't want to open it, here is the full stacktrace in plain text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/management/commands/schemamigration.py", line 87, in handle
    migrations = Migrations(app, force_creation=True, verbose_creation=int(verbosity) > 0)
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 64, in __call__
    self.instances[app_label] = super(MigrationsMetaclass, self).__call__(app_label_to_app_module(app_label), **kwds)
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.set_application(application, force_creation, verbose_creation)
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 163, in set_application
    self._load_migrations_module(application.migrations)
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 170, in _load_migrations_module
    dirname = self.migrations_dir()
  File "/home/hogar/Development/python/django/enviroments/share_this/lib/python3.3/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 132, in migrations_dir
    return os.path.dirname(module.__file__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Comment: I would like to see the solution to this problem because I'm having this also...

Comment: @RobDel I found the solution. See the answer below.

Comment: @RobDel In my case the problem was that the `migrations` directory was present when I issued the command `./manage.py schemamigration app --initial`. After deleting it, everything worked fine.

Comment: I also deleted the database migration entries and it worked. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was using python3.3 for the whole project but the initial `python manage.py syncdb` command was entered using pyhon2.7, which will give me several issues later.

I noticed this after generate the project from the scratch and look an error in [the output of `manage.py syncdb`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6728648/).

Then I deleted all the info from postgre-sql and, after `source bin/activate`, run `python3 manage.py syncdb`.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness I'm highlighting @rara_tiru 's answer from the comments as an answer as it was also my issue: I also had a migrations folder in my app, when the migrations folder was removed, it worked. Using Python 3.3 / South 1.0 / Django 1.6.5.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Django 1.5 if you have empty "migrations" directories the `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'` error will also happen.